# flutter web release showing blank screen

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I am trying to use release mode of my app. Here are the methods i have tried:

1-I executed `flutter clean`

2-I executed `flutter build web --release`

3-I executed `flutter run -d chrome --release`

On 3rd command it works fine:
[image]

But when I open `project/build/web/index.html` it shows blank screen:
[image]

Does anybody know the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In index.html you sould see a basehref. The flutter site is displayed only if the base href matches to te domain in which it is hosted. Try hosting it and adding the relevant base href. You can also delete this line and it should work as expected

Comment: I can't run it on localhost?

Comment: To run in local you just do flutter run -d chrome

Comment: I used it already, it works. But i am talking about index.html . Doesn't it work independently?

Comment: No unless you host it i believe

Comment: To run the release version you can also do flutter run --release

Comment: I will try to run it on Django server that it is connected and reply back .

Answer (score 1):

Open your  `web` folder with vscode and open `index.html`, It will show like

[image]

And use *Live Server* extension

[image]

And then run by tapping  `Go live`

[image]

Comment: I don't use VS.I use Android Studio.

Comment: This plugin should be available in android studio too

Comment: Then I think you might need local server  like xamp, you can install VS Code, and it is lighter. We aren't just running html but also loading others data

Comment: I searched,it is not.

Comment: To run a website, you need server

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I have used this extension(live server) before but at that time I was not working for flutter web.

Comment: @ᴅᴇʙᴊᴇᴇᴛ it was  just for test case for release version